# Making a public member accessed application wide

Tags: java, properties, visibility

I have the following class that loads from a property file some strings:

```
public class AuthorizationUtils {

  @Inject
  @Named("authorizedcodes")
  private static Properties authorizedcodesProperties;

  private AuthorizationUtils() {
  }

  private static List<String> getAuthorizationStrings(){
    List<String> listAuthorizedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    String listAuthorizedCodes = authorizedcodesProperties.getProperty("list.authorizedcodes");
    List<String> listAutorizedCodesString = List<String> items = Arrays.asList(listAuthorizedCodes.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    for(String authorizedCode:listAutorizedCodesString){
       listAuthorizedStrings.add(authorizedcodesProperties.getProperty(authorizedCode));
    }
    return listAuthorizedStrings;
  }
}
```

It loads the properties from this property file :

```
list.authorizedcodes=101,102,103
101=Foo
102=Bar
103=Prop
104=This
105=One
106=Won't
107=Be
108=Retrieved
```

I'm trying to make the `getAuthorizationStrings` called once so that the filtered properties could be accessed application wide and the call will be optimized.

What I tried so far is creating a static public member like this :

```
public static List<String> listAuthorizedStrings = getAuthorizationStrings();
```

But this doesn't work as in debug mode I can see the method called every time I access the public member.

Question : How can I make a public list initialized only and only once et accessed by the whole application ?

Regards.

Comment: Did my answer help your problem :) or is there something still not making sense??

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `lazy loading`, which only initilize the public member if it is non existent. This needs to be an method.

```
private static List<String> listAuthorizedStrings;

public static List<String> GetListAuthorizedStrings() 
{
    if(listAuthorizedStrings== null)
        listAuthorizedStrings= getAuthorizationStrings();

    return listAuthorizedStrings;
}
```

If you know call `GetListAuthorizedStrings()`, it will only load the file once. This logic could also be implemented in `getAuthorizationStrings()` method. But in my opinion doesn,t make sense because of the `return` type and the generation.